# Why is PyQt5 not displaying button?

Tags: python, pyqt

When the menu class is inheriting from QWidgets class, the button is displayed, however, when is inheriting from QMainWindow the same button doesnt display. I've searched everywhere but couldn't find a explanation.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QFormLayout, QPushButton, QApplication, QWidget
import sys


class Menu(QMainWindow):
    """
    Create menu object
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        Initialize main menu
        """
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.file = None
        self.fields_create()
        self.create_table()

    def fields_create(self):
        """
        Create buttons and LineEdits
        """
        # Settings Button
        self.settings_btn = QPushButton()
        self.settings_btn.setText("Settings")
        self.settings_btn.clicked.connect(self.settings_click)

    def create_table(self):
        """
        create and display table
        """
        self.flo = QFormLayout()
        self.flo.addRow(self.settings_btn)
        self.setLayout(self.flo)

    def settings_click(self):
        print("clicked")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Menu()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: QMainWindow has its own internal layout, which cannot be accessed to add other widgets. A *central widget* must be set instead, as explained in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework). Create a container QWidget, set the layout on it, and then call `setCentralWidget()` with that widget.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to replace :

```
self.settings_btn = QPushButton()
```

with

```
self.settings_btn = QPushButton(self)
```

Comment: While this partially works around the proposed issue, it doesn't really solve the problem, which is based on the fact that no layout can be directly set on a QMainWindow. The given `self.flo` layout will be completely useless by only setting the parent on the child widget. A proper [central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) must be *always* set instead, and any layout has to be eventually set on that widget.